# Which node server for creating Ethereum keypairs and sending transaction programatically?

Tags: private-key, infura, public-key

I need to create Key Pairs, and send transactions from my server program (probably node.js.) The code part is clear -- at least in terms of available examples -- and I know where to go with it.

My question is, once the Key Pair is created, how do I publish it to Ethereum? Do I need something like Infura?

Same question regarding how to publish a transaction. I'm assuming the answer would be the same too.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is to install [geth](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Installing-Geth). Then [manage accounts](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Managing-your-accounts) for adding the new account to Ethereum.

There is also a [JavaScript library](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/getting-started.html), and one of its functions is to sign and send transactions.

Example for a library that can generate Ethereum keys with `node.js` can be found [here](https://github.com/ethereumjs/keythereum). There are probably other libraries with similar function.